# returning select value using Visual Basic 2010 oleDB

Tags: vb.net, excel, oledb

I'm trying to read a excel cell with visual basic 2010 ( I'm really new to this) and I think I finally did it BUT I have no clue how to return the result. 
It should end up in the clipboard or msgBox from there I'll find my way :D
I searched for two hours now but didnt find the solution... please help me

Thanks

```
      Private Sub Button13_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button13.Click
    cn.ConnectionString = "provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=C:\Users\marcelf\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\bin\Debug\DB.xls;extended properties=excel 8.0;"
    cn.Open()

    With cm
        .Connection = cn
        .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [ccs$C1:B20] WHERE 'id' = 'German'"
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With
    cn.Close()

    MsgBox(????)



End Sub
```

EDIT: her is the updated code. I get "Could not find installable ISAM

```
        Private Sub Button13_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button13.Click
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    Try
        Using con
            'added HDR=No to the extended properties of the connection string
            con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=C:\Users\marcelf\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplicat'ion1\bin\Debug\DB.xls;extended properties=excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"
            con.Open()
            Using cmd = New OleDbCommand
                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [ccs$C1:C20] WHERE 'id' = 'German'"
                Using oRDR As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                    While (oRDR.Read)
                        MsgBox(oRDR.GetValue(0)) 'gets the first returned column
                    End While
                End Using
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

EDIT: That's what worked for me:

```
    Private Sub Button13_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button13.Click
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    Try
        Using con
            'added HDR=No to the extended properties of the connection string
            con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\marcelf\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\bin\Debug\DB.xls;Mode=3;User ID=Admin;Password=;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"
            con.Open()

            Using cmd = New OleDbCommand
                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Service FROM [ccs$] WHERE id='" & ComboBox1.SelectedItem & "'"
                Using oRDR As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                    While (oRDR.Read)
                        MsgBox(oRDR.GetValue(0)) 'gets the first returned column
                    End While
                End Using
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO. In the future you should show us all of your code. Since you tagged OleDB and vb.net, the following implements what you are trying to accomplish. I included the Form Class so the Imports statements could be shown, but you can just copy and paste the click event code after insuring you Class includes the Imports. Note, I have not tested this code but it should work. Let me know if you need clarification or additional help.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button13_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button13.Click
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection
        Try
            Using con
                'added HDR=No to the extended properties of the connection string
                ' **EDIT**
                con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\marcelf\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplicat'ion1\bin\Debug\DB.xls;Mode=3;User ID=Admin;Password=;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"
                con.Open()
                Using cmd = New OleDbCommand
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [ccs$C1:B20] WHERE 'id' = 'German'"
                    Using oRDR As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                        While (oRDR.Read)
                            MsgBox(oRDR.GetValue(0)) 'gets the first returned column
                        End While
                    End Using
                    con.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
        Finally
            con.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, that makes sense but I recieve an error: "Could not find installable ISAM." pointing to "Throw New Exception(ex.Message)"

Comment: You will need to use "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" instead of  ole.4. I edited my answer. You may also need to change HDR=Yes.

Comment: I am confident that your problem lies in your connection string. I substituted it with one that has worked for me on .xls files. If this doesn't work you must search for threads that contain your error message.

Comment: IT WORKS! Thanks Ron, you're a Star!!

Comment: Glad to hear that. On SO, it is customary for questioners to accept correct answers.